# How to let Spark output print on separate new lines?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently my spark console prints like this, which is not very readable:

[image]

I want it to print each StructField item on a new line, so that it's easier to read. What should I do? Thanks.

Update: 
I'm actually following this tutorial (http://www.nodalpoint.com/spark-data-frames-from-csv-files-handling-headers-column-types/), the author is able to print line by line without pprint. I wonder how he/she did that.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `pprint` like this:

```
import pprint
pprint(fields)
```

but if you're trying to print schema it is better to use `DataFrame.printSchema`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice workaround. I'm actually following this tutorial (http://www.nodalpoint.com/spark-data-frames-from-csv-files-handling-headers-column-types/), the author is able to print line by line without pprint. I wonder how he/she did that.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use:

```
fields.foreach(println)
```

It also works when you retrieve data from an rdd or dataframe:

```
myDf.collect().foreach(println)
```